# Error:(147, 53) error: constructor TrainingFragment in class TrainingFragment cannot be applied to given types; required: String,String,int

Tags: java, android-studio

This is the line that gives me error:-

"Error:(147, 53) error: constructor TrainingFragment in class TrainingFragment cannot be applied to given types;
    required: String,String,int
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Here is my part of code in which i got error while creating list in MainActivity.java:-

```
private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            GalleryFragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
            return galleryFragment;
        case 2:
            TrainingFragment trainingFragment = new TrainingFragment();
            return trainingFragment;
        case 3:
            NutritionFragment nutritionFragment = new NutritionFragment();
            return nutritionFragment;
        case 4:
            ContactFragment contactFragment = new ContactFragment();
            return contactFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}
```

TrainingFragment.java

```
public class TrainingFragment extends Fragment {
String name;
String detail;
int image;

public TrainingFragment(String name, String detail, int image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.detail = detail;
    this.image = image;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
    }
}
```

TrainingAdapter.java

```
public class TrainingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TrainingFragment> {
Context context;
List<TrainingFragment> TrainingFragmentList;
TrainingFragment TrainingFragment;



public TrainingAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<TrainingFragment> TrainingFragmentObject) {
    super(context, resource, TrainingFragmentObject);

    this.context = context;
    this.TrainingFragmentList = TrainingFragmentObject;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.training_list,null);
    TextView name;
    ImageView image;
    name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);

//looping TrainingFragment list
    TrainingFragment = TrainingFragmentList.get(position);
    name.setText(TrainingFragment.getName());
    image.setImageResource(TrainingFragment.getImage());

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", TrainingFragmentList.get(position).getName());
            intent.putExtra("detail", TrainingFragmentList.get(position).getDetail());
            intent.putExtra("image", TrainingFragmentList.get(position).getImage());

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code and explanation aren't clear enough. Please explain what exactly you are trying to do in English, perhaps i might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code misses a no-arg constructor, you must pass name, detail and number of imaget to `TrainingFragment`.

```
case 2:
    TrainingFragment trainingFragment = new TrainingFragment();
```

should be

```
case 2:
    TrainingFragment trainingFragment = new TrainingFragment("name", "detail", 1);
```

As an alternative, add a no-arg constructor to `TrainingFragment` class.